# Error in Codeblocks: error ld 1 returned exit status

Tags: c, module, codeblocks

I'm mostly a beginning programmer with modules, and this error appears most of the times and I can't figure it out how to resolve it...

IDE is Code::Blocks 17.12

The error is:

> ||=== Build: Debug in biblioteca (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>
> ||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
>
> ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Here's the code:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "funzioni.h"

int main()
{
bool uscito=false;
do{
menuscelte();
int option = getoption();

switch(option){
    case 0: printf("Uscita dal programma...");
            uscito=true;
            break;
    case 1: acquisiscidati();
            break;

    default: printf("Inserire un'opzione valida\n\n");

    break;

}
}while(!(uscito==true));
return 0;
}
```

funzioni.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dati.h"
FILE *fp;

void aprifile(char* nome, char* tipo){
fp = fopen(nome, tipo);
}

void chiudifile(){
fclose(fp);
}

void acquisiscidati(){
int cod, annopubb;
char autore[MAXAUTORE];
char titolo[MAXTITOLO];

printf("Inserire codice libro: ");
scanf("%d", &cod);
printf("Inserire autore libro: ");
scanf("%s", autore);
printf("Inserire titolo libro: ");
scanf("%s", titolo);
printf("Inserire anno di pubblicazione: ");
scanf("%d", &annopubb);

aprifile(nomefile, "a+");
fprintf(fp, "%d %s %s %d", cod, autore, titolo, annopubb);
chiudifile();

}
```

funzioni.h

```
#ifndef FUNZIONI_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNZIONI_H_INCLUDED

#include "dati.h"

void acquisiscidati();
void aprifile(char* nome, char* tipo);
void chiudifile();

#endif // FUNZIONI_H_INCLUDED
```

dati.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void menuscelte(){
printf("Menu'\n");
printf("-------------------------\n");
printf("0 - Uscita dal programma\n");
printf("1 - Acquisizione di un libro");
printf("\n");
}

int getoption(){
int option;
printf("Inserire l'opzione desiderata: ");
scanf("%d", &option);
return option;
}
```

dati.h

```
#ifndef DATI_H_INCLUDED
#define DATI_H_INCLUDED

#define MAXAUTORE 15
#define MAXTITOLO 15
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0


typedef struct{
int codice;
char autore[MAXAUTORE];
char titolo[MAXTITOLO];
int annopubb;
}ins_libro;


char* nomefile = "biblioteca.txt";

void menuscelte();
int getoption();


#endif // DATI_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: There should be some other error message, possibly mentioning 'undefined references'.  That's the important information.  The message you quote says "something failed" with no information about what.

Comment: You seem to have posted the same code for `funzioni.c` as for `main.c`

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you, I noticed and I edited that. For Jonathan: It don't say anything, expect that error, I also thought it was a strange fact...

Comment: My guess is that you get a multiple definition error because you define the variable `nomefile` in each [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) (each source file, basically) where `dati.h` is included in (directly *and* indirectly).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that was the problem, thank you man, now the code works, cheers :D